# JComboBox buscar mientras escribe en un ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, combobox

estoy intentando que mientras escriben en un **JComboBox** *arroje el resultado que va teniendo de la búsqueda en el mismo JComboBox abajo.*
La búsqueda la realiza en un ArrayList llamado **ListaDeMarcas** la verdad que soy muy nuevo como para entender al 100x100 de como funciona el array.
He logrado por mi cuenta hacer que el array me traiga la lista de una db.
Donde solo hay 2 columnas 1 que se llama **id** y la segunda que se llama **marcas**.

***El array funciona porque me llena el JComboBox.***

*Lo que no me funciona es que **cuando escriben no va realizando la búsqueda.** Preciso que cada ves que va ingresando un carácter valla buscando.
Y **tampoco va mostrando el resultado de la búsqueda** abajo como quiero. Valga la redundancia.*

**Código del Array List:**

```
    //---------------------------------MARCAS
public class ModeloDeMarcas {

    public ArrayList<ListaDeMarcas> getListaDeMarcas() {
        //CONEXION
        PanelAdministrativo pa = new PanelAdministrativo();
        pa.conexionDb();
        //END CONEXION
        Statement ejecuto;
        ResultSet rs;
        ArrayList<ListaDeMarcas> listaMarcas = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ejecuto = pa.con.createStatement();
            rs = ejecuto.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM marcas");
            while (rs.next()) {
                ListaDeMarcas Marcas = new ListaDeMarcas();
                Marcas.setMARCA(rs.getString("MARCA"));
                listaMarcas.add(Marcas);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("e = " + e);
        }
        return listaMarcas;
    }
}

private void rellenoListaDeMarcas() {
    ModeloDeMarcas mMarcas = new ModeloDeMarcas();
    ArrayList<ListaDeMarcas> listMarcas = mMarcas.getListaDeMarcas();
    buscador.removeAllItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < listMarcas.size(); i++) {
        buscador.addItem(listMarcas.get(i).getMARCA());
    }
}

public class ListaDeMarcas {

    public String MARCA;

    public String getMARCA() {
        return MARCA;
    }

    public void setMARCA(String MARCA) {
        this.MARCA = MARCA;
    }
}
```

Código que utilizo para el evento cuando escribe **(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)**:

```
private void jComboBox1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    ArrayList<ListaDeMarcas> lista = new ArrayList<ListaDeMarcas>();//-------->ARRAY QUE TRAE LA LISTA DESDE LA DB
    String palabra = (String) demo.getText();//-------->OBTENGO LA PALABRA QUE VOY A BUSCAR DESDE EL JCOMBOBOX
    boolean existe = lista.contains(palabra);
    if (existe) {
        System.out.println("LO ENCONTRE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO EXISTE, SIGA BUSCANDO (LOSER)");
    }
}
```

He visto en un foro en ingles que deberia implementar el Arrays.asList(nombreDelArray). Queda asi el codigo como el siguiente. El problema esta en que me dice que mi array no no puede convertirse en string.
En ingles dice:

> ***Incompatible types: ArrayList<borrador.ListaDeMarcas> cannot be
> converted to String[]***

```
        //ArrayList<ListaDeMarcas> listaX = new ArrayList<ListaDeMarcas>()CON ESTE ARRAY ME DA ERROR NO SE PUEDE CONVERTIR A STRING
    String[] listaX = {"ARCOR","CATA","MANGO","PIPI","TOTO"};;//ARRAY DE PRUEBA A STRING FUNCIONA PERFECTO
    String palabra = (String) demo.getText();//-------->OBTENGO LA PALABRA QUE VOY A BUSCAR DESDE EL JCOMBOBOX
    Arrays.asList(listaX).contains(palabra);
    if (searchList(listaX, palabra)) {
        System.out.println("LO ENCONTRE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO EXISTE, SIGA BUSCANDO (LOSER)");
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema que encuentro es que no comparas la palabra que buscas con lo que contiene la array, osea, la combobox.
Prueba a adaptar esto a tu último método:

```
ArrayList.contains("String que quieres comparar");
```

Un saludo y espero que te funcione.

Comment: Hola Jose, te entendi perfecto, intente agregarlo como String al modificador String palabra = (String) demo.getText(); para que quede asi pero no funciono. Tambien aclare el codigo para que sea mas simple de entender. Invoco el array, creo el string para que sea utilizado en la busqueda, y reemplace el indexOF por contains, ya que leyendo entendi que el indexOf me busca valores y le debo dar valores para comparar, en cambio yo preciso buscar palabras o nombres, por eso ahora puse en el codigo contains.